# Shimano Deore 11s derailleur and shifter with a 9s casette 11-46t (Sunrace)

Tags: derailleur, shifter, 1x11

I was questioning if can I fit an 11s Deore derailleur with shifters to a 9s 11-46t Sunrace cassette?
I've got the doubt because I need to change my derailleur to one that can tolerate up to 46t cassette because my old Slx with the derailleur hanger extender can't do the job very well.
The options are limited to Chinese derailleurs, Sunrace, Ltwoo or S-Ride. That's why I was wondering if an 11s Deore derailleur that can tolerate up to 51t could do the work for me, and have a better quality derailleur.

if anyone can help me pls!

Comment: 9 speed cassette sprocket spacings (4.35 mm) are quite different from 11 speed (3.9 mm). This won’t work. Do you really want to run a 9 speed 11–46t cassette? The gear steps are huge. Why not use 11 speed if you already have the derailleur and shifter?

Comment: This is by the way why triple chainrings were invented.

Comment: SunRace are Taiwanese.

Comment: You can also consider Microshift Advent 9-speed (or Advent X — 10s-speed), that have very good reviews and are cheaper than Deore.

Comment: @Michael there's a chance that an 11 speed cassette may not fit.  Though its also possible with a hokking-great dinnerplate cog that there will be space inside the cassette to overhang the freehub a bit.   Ideally OP would borrow an 11 speed cassette and see if it slides on their wheel - that's the kind of thing a bike shop would have as a test item, hard to justify buying one if it might not fit.

Comment: Could you explain why you specifically want the 9s cassette? There may be an unusual reason that warrants this combination, but on its own it seems odd.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot combine these shifters, derailleur and cassette. It makes very little sense to have a different number of speeds on a cassette and on a shifter. One can sometimes have a different number of speeds on the derailleur if the cable pull ratio is the same. But it is only the same for up to 9-speed (MTB). 10 speed drivetrains have a different ratio and 11 speed drivetrains have a different ratio.

Using an 11-speed shifter and an 11-speed derailleur with the hope of only using 9 positions on a 9-speed cassette won't work either as the distance of the sprockets will be incorrect.

The most natural setup appears to be to have all components at 11-sppeed (or 10-speed, if sufficient). 9-speed (at least within the limitations of Shimano specs) is probably too limited for 1x in hilly terrain.

Comment: I'll go with the full 9s setup then, Thank u very much

Comment: @cristianvargas bonus, 9 speed cassettes are a lot more affordable than 11 speed ones.

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you mix Shimano Deore 11s derailleur with an SRAM 1:1 9-speed shifter it could work:

- the sprocket pitch is 4.35 mm ([source](https://bike.bikegremlin.com/3573/bicycle-cassette-rear-chainrings-standards/#3))
  This is what you have to match with your derailleur + shifter
- the derailleur has a movement/cable-pull ratio of 1.1 ([source, see Shimano and table](https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1278/bicycle-rear-derailleur-compatibility/#1))
- thus you need a pull of 4 mm ≈ 3.95 mm = 4.35 mm / 1.1 which the SRAM 9-speed shifters have ([source, see SRAM and table](https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1339/bicycle-rear-shifter-compatibility/#4)). The error over the 9 speeds is only 0.36 mm or 8.4% of the sprocket distance - this shouldn't be a problem and is problably below the measurement error of the sprocket pitch, pull ratio and shifter pull

however, since it's mixed, don't expect it to work **until you've tried it**. 
I'd expect the "chinese" derailleurs that you mention to work better before trying it.